# How to fix unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'?

Tags: python

```
# Class the LinearRegression
class LinearRegression(object):
    __x_List = []
    __y_list = []
    __slope = None
    __intercept = None
    #constructor aka magic functions dunder methods
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self,x_list,y_list):
        self.__x_list = x_list
        self.__y_list = y_list
        self.calculate
    def mean(self,my_list):
        return sum(my_list) / len(my_list)

    def mean_diff(self,myList, my_mean_sum):
        return [x-my_mean_sum for x in myList]
        #Return a prediction for a given X value
    def calculate(self):
        #get mean for each
        #x_mean_sum = sum(__x_list)/len(__x_list)
        x_mean_sum = self.mean(self.__x_list)
        y_mean_sum = self.mean(self.__y_list)

        x_mean_diff = self.mean_diff(self.__x_list, x_mean_sum)
        y_mean_diff = self.mean_diff(self.__y_list, y_mean_sum)

        #Product
        xy_product = sum([x*y for x,y in zip(x_mean_diff,y_mean_diff)])
        #x_squared
        x_mean_diff_squared = [pow(x,2) for x in x_mean_diff]
        x_mean_diff_squared_sum = sum(x_mean_diff_squared)
        print(x_mean_diff_squared_sum)

        #get slope
        self.__slope = xy_product/x_mean_diff_squared_sum
        #get intercept
        self.__intercept = y_mean_sum - (x_mean_sum * self.__slope)

        # Return a prediction for a given X value
    def predict(self,x_value):
        return (int(self.__slope or 0) * x_value) + self.__intercept
#___________________
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(bill_list, tip_list)

model.predict(225) --- shows an error
```

Above is my coding.
**Error shows: **
return (int(self.__slope or 0) * x_value) + self.__intercept
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
Can anyone help me fix it? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not actually calling `self.calculate` in `fit` because there's no parentheses after the function name. Since `calculate` doesn't run, `self.__intercept` is not set to another value so it remains None.

You can diagnose these issues easily by throwing in some print statements in your functions to make sure everything is turning out as expected. In this case, since the issue is with self.__intercept, you'd start with printing out that value just after it is set in `calculate`. Once you ran that you'd have seen that it wasn't printing out there in the first place, so you'd have a hint that `calculate` isn't run.

Comment: Yes. I have fixed it. Thanks.